# Disable keyboard list popup when pressing alt + shift

Tags: windows, windows-10

Recently I installed newest windows update (1903).

Until this version when I changed keyboard (alt + shift) it didn't appear on screen, but now it does. How can I disable that window? See photo.

[image]